# ReplaceThen and ReplaceAt - Cross between ReplacePart, Replace, and Extract -- Request for Comment

Tags: function-construction, replacement, code-review, code-request, hold

REWRITE: Multiple edits were hurting clarity

**Overview:**

I'm doing some work involving injecting code into held expressions, and found that I was repeating myself in a couple areas related to the available `Replace` and `ReplacePart` syntaxes.  I'll call the two patterns I found myself repeating "`ReplaceThen`" and "`ReplaceAt`".

Below, I define `ReplaceThen` and `ReplaceAt`, including:

- Definition
- Minimal example
- Constraints
- Motivation (why do I want this?)

After that, I've included the code for my first versions of `ReplaceThen` and `ReplaceAt`.

**Request:**

I'm looking for some feedback (this post is a request-for-comment) on my first versions of `ReplaceThen` and `ReplaceAt`.  I'm a bit of a newbie, and I want to make sure that:

1. I considered all the edge-cases, and my code is "functionally correct" in the general case
2. Performance is reasonably-close to optimal, for code written in native WFL.
3. Pattern guards are effective without being overly-onerous
4. Flexibility is sufficient enough for functions intended to cover general-case use -- do you have any use-cases you run into yourself that aren't currently solved, but could be with reasonable modifications?  Do you have any use-cases that might motivate me to create a 3rd/N'th function within this family of `Replace` extensions?
5. Forget about the "..., for code written in native WFL" restriction above.  Might these warrant being written in C?  My guess is that since `Replace`, `ReplacePart`, `Extract`, and `Dispatch` are all heavily-optimized already, it's probably not worth writing everything from scratch.

This post is a request-for-comment (RFC) on these two functions in-general, with a specific emphasis on the above questions.

---

**Function 1: `ReplaceThen`**

**Definition:**

Perform a normal `Replace`, but allow wrapping the result in an arbitrary head ***after** replacement, but **before** any subsequent evaluation*.

**Minimal example - input:**

```
ReplaceThen[Unevaluated[1+1],1->2,{-1},Hold]
```

**Minimal example - desired output:**

```
Hold[2+2]
```

c.f.: `Replace[Unevaluated[1+1], 1->2, {-1}]` would return `4`

**Constraints**

1. Any techniques used to implement `ReplaceThen` (such as additions of `Hold`s) should be transparent to the end-user.  For example, if I call `ReplaceThen[Unevaluated[1+1],Plus->Times,{1},Hold,Heads->True]`, my level specification of `{1}` should be interpreted exactly the same way that regular `Replace` interprets its level specifications.
2. Any techniques used to implement `ReplaceThen` (such as addition of `Hold`s) should be "bulletproof" in that no rules supplied by the end-user should be capable of "breaking" the function.  Specifically, `ReplaceThen` must support edge-cases where the end-user deliberately supplies rules which transform `Hold`, `HoldComplete`, or an arbitrary head such as `Blank[]`.

**Motivation:**

Conveniently, `Extract` offers us an optional third parameter where we can wrap the extracted contents in an arbitrary head before evaluation.  From the documentation:

```
Extract[expr,pos,h] 
extracts parts of expr, wrapping each of them with head h before evaluation.
```

Unfortunately, `Replace` does not offer the same convenience argument out-of-the-box.  **The reason for creating `ReplaceThen` which supports a "wrap in head `h`" argument is the same as the reason for supporting a "wrap in head `h`" argument for `Extract`: passing the value *returned from* `Replace` to a downstream function is *not* the same as performing a replacement, then wrapping the replaced expression in an arbitrary head *prior to evaluation*.**  It only makes a difference if the replaced expression *would* evaluate to something else in the first place, but that is the entire subject of this post.

**Bottom line:**

This is not a complicated function, and instead of:

```
ReplaceThen[Unevaluated[1+1],Plus->Times,{1},Hold,Heads->True]
```

If you were *only* performing a one-off case, you could certainly directly perform:

```
Replace[Hold[1+1], Plus->Times, {2}, Heads->True]
```

(just adjust level specification from `{1}` to `{2}` in this example)

To re-emphasize: the entire point of this function is to handle the general-case correctly (with respect to the above constraints) and conveniently for arbitrary user-provided rules, so that you don't have to choose between technical correctness and verbosity.

---

**Function 2: `ReplaceAt`**

**Definition:**

Perform a normal `Replace` (including arbitrary pattern rules, not just substitution of one part with a verbatim-substituted replacement part like `ReplacePart` does), but only on a portion of an expression specified by an arbitrary part specification (not just a level specification like `Replace` takes).

**Minimal example - input:**

```
ReplaceAt[Hold[1+1,1+1],1->2,{2},{-1}]
```

**Minimal example - desired output:**

```
Hold[1+1,2+2]
```

c.f.: `Replace[Hold[1+1,1+1],1->2,{-1}]` would return `Hold[2+2,2+2]`, and `Hold[1+1,Evaluate@Replace[Unevaluated[1+1],1->2,{-1}]]` would return `Hold[1+1,4]`

**Constraints**

Same as `ReplaceThen`:

1. Interpret a level specification of e.g. `{1}` exactly the same way that `Replace` does, regardless of whether the implementation includes e.g. an internal `Hold`.  Interpret a part specification of e.g. {1} exactly the same way that `Extract` does.
2. Be bulletproof to arbitrary user-supplied rules, including the edge-cases noted for `ReplaceThen`.

**Motivation:**

**The reason for creating an extension of `Replace` accepting a part specification argument, versus just using `MapAt` on `Replace` (or a closure containing it) is the same reason `ReplacePart` exists, versus just mapping `newExpr&` to some part of an expression: it performs the replacement *prior to evaluation or without evaluation* of the larger expression.**. Remember, the semantics of `Replace` are that replacements are performed "...even when parts have Hold or related wrappers" (including `HoldComplete` or functions with `HoldAllComplete` attributes), so even using `MapAt[ReplaceAll[rules], ...` followed by `MapAt[Evaluate, ...]` would not provide these semantics.

---

The code follows below...:

First, some boilerplate: setup a `HoldComplete`-like wrapper, and some dispatch tables for modifying user-provided rules and level specifications:

```
ClearAll[ReplaceAt`HoldComplete, partSpecPatt, replaceRulePatt, 
levelSpecPattern, ReplaceThen, ReplaceAt]

(* Surrogate for HoldComplete: in case rules themselves transform HoldComplete *)
SetAttributes[ReplaceAt`HoldComplete, HoldAllComplete]

(* Boilerplate pattern guards *)

partSpecPatt = _Integer | _Span | 
   All | {partSpecElements___ /; (And @@ 
       Thread@Unevaluated@MatchQ[{partSpecElements}, partSpecPatt])};
replaceRulePatt = _Rule | _RuleDelayed | {(_Rule | _RuleDelayed) ..};
levelSpecPattern = _Integer | All | 
   Infinity | -Infinity | {Repeated[_Integer | 
      Infinity | -Infinity, {1, 2}]};

(* Translate arbitrary rule(s) to never modify ReplaceAt`HoldComplete *)
(* e.g. if the rule was _[x_]:>Identity[x] *)

ruleExceptTransform = 
  Dispatch[(h : Rule | RuleDelayed)[l_, r_] :> 
    h[Except[ReplaceAt`HoldComplete | _ReplaceAt`HoldComplete, l], r]];

(* Translate level spec to account for ReplaceAt`HoldComplete *)

levelSpecTransform = 
  Dispatch[{{n1_, n2_Integer?Positive} :> {n1, n2 + 1}, 
    n_Integer?Positive :> n + 1, {n_Integer?Positive} :> {n + 1}}];

(* Sugar: make user calls to Options[...] return something *)
(* Allow specifying attributes, e.g. HoldFirst, for Operator forms*)

Options[ReplaceThen] = 
  Join[Options[Replace], {OperatorHold -> {SequenceHold}}];
Options[ReplaceAt] = 
  Join[Options[Replace], {OperatorHold -> {SequenceHold}}];
SetAttributes[ReplaceThen, SequenceHold]
SetAttributes[ReplaceAt, SequenceHold]
```

Next, here are `ReplaceThen` and `ReplaceAt`:

```
With[{ruleExceptTransform = ruleExceptTransform, 
  levelSpecTransform = levelSpecTransform},
 
 ReplaceThen[expr_, rules : replaceRulePatt, 
   levelSpec : levelSpecPattern : {0}, 
   wrap_Symbol : Function[x, x, SequenceHold], 
   opts : OptionsPattern[ReplaceThen]] := wrap @@ Replace[
    ReplaceAt`HoldComplete[expr],
    Replace[rules, ruleExceptTransform, {0, 1}],
    Replace[levelSpec, levelSpecTransform],
    FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Replace]]
    ];
 
 ReplaceAt[expr_, rules : replaceRulePatt, partSpec : partSpecPatt, 
   levelSpec : levelSpecPattern : {0}, 
   opts : OptionsPattern[ReplaceAt]] :=
  ReplacePart[
   Unevaluated@expr,
   Replace[
    Replace[
     Extract[Unevaluated@expr, partSpec, ReplaceAt`HoldComplete],
     Replace[rules, ruleExceptTransform, {0, 1}],
     Replace[levelSpec, levelSpecTransform],
     FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Replace]]
     ],
    ReplaceAt`HoldComplete[x_] :> RuleDelayed[partSpec, x]
    ]
   ];
 
 ]
```

We might as well support Operator forms of the above, while we're at it:

```
ReplaceThen[rules : replaceRulePatt, 
   levelSpec_ : levelSpecPattern : {0}, 
   wrap_Symbol : Function[x, x, SequenceHold], 
   opts : OptionsPattern[ReplaceThen]] := 
  Function[expr, ReplaceThen[expr, rules, levelSpec, wrap, opts], 
     Evaluate@OptionValue@OperatorHold] /. DownValues@ReplaceThen /. 
   Verbatim[FilterRules][x_, y__] :> RuleCondition@FilterRules[x, y];

(* Remember Unevaluated if not inlining with DownValues *)

ReplaceAt[rules : replaceRulePatt, partSpec : partSpecPatt, 
   levelSpec : levelSpecPattern : {0}, 
   opts : OptionsPattern[ReplaceAt]] := 
  Function[expr, ReplaceAt[expr, rules, partSpec, levelSpec, opts], 
     Evaluate@OptionValue@OperatorHold] /. DownValues@ReplaceAt /. 
   Verbatim[FilterRules][x_, y__] :> RuleCondition@FilterRules[x, y];
```

Alternatively, I could have written `ReplaceAt` in terms of `ReplaceThen`.  The below alternative relies upon the fact that `RuleDelayed` consumes `Unevaluated` from any expression which starts with `Unevaluated`:

```
ClearAll[ReplaceAt]
Options[ReplaceAt] = 
  Join[Options[Replace], {OperatorHold -> {SequenceHold}}];
SetAttributes[ReplaceAt, SequenceHold]

ReplaceAt[expr_, rules : replaceRulePatt, partSpec : partSpecPatt, 
  levelSpec : levelSpecPattern : {0}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 With[{subExpr = 
    Extract[Unevaluated@expr, partSpec, 
     ReplaceThen[rules, levelSpec, Unevaluated, opts, 
      OperatorHold -> {SequenceHold, HoldFirst}]]},
  ReplacePart[Unevaluated@expr, partSpec :> subExpr]]

ReplaceAt[rules : replaceRulePatt, partSpec : partSpecPatt, 
  levelSpec : levelSpecPattern : {0}, opts : OptionsPattern[]
  ] := With[{replaceThenOp = 
    ReplaceThen[rules, levelSpec, Unevaluated, opts, 
     OperatorHold -> {SequenceHold, HoldFirst}]},
  Function[expr, 
   With[{subExpr = Extract[Unevaluated@expr, partSpec, replaceThenOp]},
    ReplacePart[Unevaluated@expr, partSpec :> subExpr]], 
   Evaluate@OptionValue@OperatorHold]]
```

That concludes the function definitions.  Now, let's test the functions against the minimal examples I posted earlier (I've of course done a bit more testing than this, which I won't include, for brevity):

Input:

```
ReplaceThen[Unevaluated[1 + 1], 1 -> 2, {-1}, Hold]
ReplaceAt[Hold[1 + 1, 1 + 1], 1 -> 2, {2}, {-1}]
```

Output:

```
Hold[2 + 2]
Hold[1 + 1, 2 + 2]
```

The results are what I would expect.  That said, perhaps there are some edge-cases that I haven't thought through, or performance/flexibility could be increased.  Or perhaps you can think of an alternative way to perform the same tasks, written in WFL, which is simply more elegant.

Thanks in advance for feedback / critiques!

Comment: At a glance, from your description `ReplaceThen` is... just `Replace`? In other words, "Extract-with-third-argument" singles out a part, then does something to it. Isn't that what a transformation `Rule` does already (i.e. `Replace[ a_ :> f[a] ]`)? Also, you say that you "could not find any function which performs a Replace-like operation ... but only on a portion of an expression specified by an arbitrary part specification". Wouldn't that be `MapAt[Replace[...], yourPosition]`?

Comment: @MarcoB, added some edits above to address your points (the "why" behind making these functions)

Comment: We need minimal examples of what result you want from certain input expressions. You might find it is already easy to do what you want.

Comment: @TedErsek : Added both a minimal example for each function, and a preview of what my end-goal is with these functions (a future post will be dedicated to my real end-goal of "general-purpose evaluation-control utility functions" but I included one example I had in mind -- "`EvaluateSome`", which works as-posted, but could be both optimized and made more flexible)

Answer (score 4):

Well, I give my first shot a "C-".  Here is an updated self-corrected version, for posterity.  Maybe some unlucky shmuck who is working with held expressions can make use of this someplace in the future.

Changes:

- Change pattern guard to permit replacement rules which use nested lists of rules (an allowed syntax of regular `Replace`)
- Use `NonNegative` vs `Positive` when adjusting level specifications to account for `` ReplaceAt`HoldComplete ``
- Based on empirical performance testing, use of recursive pattern guards has terrible performance -- switch to a `Flatten`-based method for testing part specification patterns
- Operator forms were not fully "inlined" -- more computation was occurring at runtime (i.e. when the Operator was invoked) than was strictly necessary.  The new version performs more computation at creation-time (i.e. when the Operator is defined).
- Removed one variable (the replaced sub-part) from the `With` expression of `ReplaceAt` by using `Evaluate` on the RHS of the `ReplacePart` rule -- just a little cleaner
- Switched to using a giant `TemplateWith` to define all functions.  It suites my coding style better to be able to build everything in small steps, but without leaving behind a trail of side-effects.
- Note: Also included a `TemplateSubstitute` definition that is like `TemplateSlot`, but "actually works" when you're transforming one `TemplateExpression` into another `TemplateExpression`.  I find this handy.

```
ClearAll[ReplaceAt`HoldComplete, ReplaceThen, ReplaceAt]

TemplateSubstitute = 
  TemplateApply@*TemplateEvaluate@*
   TemplateVerbatim[TemplateExpression]@*TemplateExpression@*
   TemplateSlot;

TemplateApply@TemplateWith[
  {
   (* Boilerplate pattern guards *)
   
   "partSpecPattern" -> 
    PatternTest[_, 
     MatchQ[List@RepeatedNull[_Integer | _Span | All]]@*Flatten@*List],
   "replaceRulePattern" -> 
    PatternTest[_, 
     MatchQ[List@
        RepeatedNull[_Rule | _RuleDelayed]]@*(Flatten[#, 2] &)@*
      List],
   "levelSpecPattern" -> 
    PatternTest[_, 
     MatchQ[List@
        Repeated[_Integer | -Infinity | Infinity | All, {0, 
          2}]]@*(Flatten[#, 1] &)@*List],
   
   (* Guard ReplaceAt`HoldComplete from arbitrary rules *)
   (* e.g. if the rule was _[x_]:>Identity[x] *)
   
   "ruleExceptTransform" -> 
    Dispatch[(h : Rule | RuleDelayed)[l_, r_] :> 
      h[Except[ReplaceAt`HoldComplete | _ReplaceAt`HoldComplete, l], 
       r]],
   "MakeSafeRules" :> TemplateEvaluate@Replace[Dispatch@{
        TemplateSlot@"ruleExceptTransform",
        ll : {___List} :> 
         Replace[ll, TemplateSlot@"ruleExceptTransform", {2}],
        l___List :> 
         Replace[l, TemplateSlot@"ruleExceptTransform", {1}]
        }],
   
   (* Shift level spec for ReplaceAt`HoldComplete *)
   
   "ShiftLevelSpec" -> Replace@Dispatch@
      {{n1_, n2_Integer?NonNegative} :> {n1, n2 + 1}, 
       n_Integer?NonNegative :> 
        n + 1, {n_Integer?NonNegative} :> {n + 1}},
   
   (* Default options and attributes *)
   
   "ReplaceOptions" -> Options[Replace],
   "DefaultOptions" :> 
    TemplateEvaluate@
     Unevaluated@
      Append[OperatorHold -> {SequenceHold}]@
       TemplateSlot@"ReplaceOptions",
   "DefaultAttributes" -> SequenceHold,
   
   (* DownValue LHS *)
   
   "ReplaceThenLHS" :> 
    ReplaceThen[repThenExpr_, 
     rules : TemplateSlot@"replaceRulePattern", 
     levelSpec : TemplateSlot@"levelSpecPattern" : {0}, 
     wrap : _Symbol | _Function : Function[x, x, SequenceHold], 
     opts : OptionsPattern[ReplaceThen]],
   
   "ReplaceThenOperatorLHS" :> 
    TemplateEvaluate@Unevaluated@Rest@TemplateSlot@"ReplaceThenLHS",
   
   "ReplaceAtLHS" :> 
    ReplaceAt[repAtExpr_, rules : TemplateSlot@"replaceRulePattern", 
     partSpec : TemplateSlot@"partSpecPattern", 
     levelSpec : TemplateSlot@"levelSpecPattern" : {0}, 
     opts : OptionsPattern[ReplaceAt]],
   
   "ReplaceAtOperatorLHS" :> 
    TemplateEvaluate@Unevaluated@Rest@TemplateSlot@"ReplaceAtLHS",
   
   (* Main body *)
   
   "ProcessArgsTemplate" :> With[
     {
      safeRules = TemplateSlot["MakeSafeRules"]@rules,
      shiftedLevelSpec = TemplateSlot["ShiftLevelSpec"]@levelSpec,
      replaceOpts = FilterRules[{opts}, TemplateSlot@"ReplaceOptions"] 
      },
     TemplateSlot@1
     ],
   
   "ReplaceThenDirect" :> 
    Apply[wrap]@
     Replace[ReplaceAt`HoldComplete@repThenExpr, safeRules, 
      shiftedLevelSpec, replaceOpts],
   
   "ReplaceThenOperator" :> 
    Function[repThenExpr, TemplateSlot@"ReplaceThenDirect", 
     Evaluate@OptionValue@OperatorHold],
   
   "ReplaceAtHelper" :> 
    TemplateEvaluate[
     Apply[Unevaluated] @@@ TemplateSubstitute@"ReplaceThenDirect"],
   
   "ReplaceAtDirect" :> 
    ReplacePart[Unevaluated@repAtExpr, partSpec :> Evaluate@
       Extract[Unevaluated@repAtExpr, partSpec, 
        Function[repThenExpr, 
         TemplateSlot@"ReplaceAtHelper", {HoldAll, SequenceHold}]]],
   
   "ReplaceAtOperator" :> 
    Function[repAtExpr, TemplateSlot@"ReplaceAtDirect", 
     Evaluate@OptionValue@OperatorHold]
   
   },
  TemplateExpression[
   (* Surrogate for HoldComplete: 
   in case rules themselves transform HoldComplete *)
   
   SetAttributes[ReplaceAt`HoldComplete, HoldAllComplete];
   
   (* Sugar: make user calls to Options[...] return something *)
   
   Options@ReplaceThen = TemplateSlot@"DefaultOptions";
   Attributes@ReplaceThen = TemplateSlot@"DefaultAttributes";
   Options@ReplaceAt = TemplateSlot@"DefaultOptions";
   Attributes@ReplaceAt = TemplateSlot@"DefaultAttributes";
   
   TemplateSlot@"ReplaceThenLHS" := 
    TemplateObject[TemplateSlot@"ProcessArgsTemplate", 
     TemplateSlot@"ReplaceThenDirect"];
   TemplateSlot@"ReplaceThenOperatorLHS" := 
    TemplateObject[TemplateSlot@"ProcessArgsTemplate", 
     TemplateSlot@"ReplaceThenOperator"];
   
   TemplateSlot@"ReplaceAtLHS" := 
    TemplateObject[TemplateSlot@"ProcessArgsTemplate", 
     TemplateSlot@"ReplaceAtDirect"];
   TemplateSlot@"ReplaceAtOperatorLHS" := 
    TemplateObject[TemplateSlot@"ProcessArgsTemplate", 
     TemplateSlot@"ReplaceAtOperator"];
   Null
   
   ]
  ]
```

Finally, since my stated purpose for these functions ("injecting code into held expressions") is rather nebulous, I'll include a **PREVIEW** of what my real end-goal is.  I'm building out some utility functions related to general-purpose evaluation control -- the first one, `EvaluateSome` would be something like the below. **Please note that the below is NOT mature yet**:

```
EvaluateSome /: 
 HoldPattern[
   mainExpr : (callHead : Except[HoldPattern | Verbatim])[callLeft___,
      eval : EvaluateSome[func_Symbol][expr__], 
     callRight___]] /;
  (FreeQ[Unevaluated@mainExpr, MakeBoxes]) := 
 ReplaceAt[Unevaluated@callHead[callLeft, expr, callRight], 
  f_func :> RuleCondition@f, {1 + Length@List@Unevaluated@callLeft}, {0, 
   Infinity}]
```

Test input:

```
F[x_] := x^2 + Integrate[Cos[y], {y, 0, 2}] //EvaluateSome[Integrate]
Definition@F
```

Output:

```
F[x_]:=x^2 + Sin[2]
```

The above simple example could be done using a `With` clause, or simply pre-defining the `Integrate` portion of the expression in a separate variable, but sometimes when you are making factory functions, things like this are just plain convenient...